# std::span as a template template argument doesn't compile with clang

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, clang, clang++

I want to use `std::span` as a template template argument to a function.
gcc seems to accept the following code, but clang rejects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6};

template <template <typename> class S>
S<int> GetSpan()
{
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    auto x = GetSpan<std::span>();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why this is the case ?

https://godbolt.org/z/Ks9M5oqKc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the second template parameter, the extent:

```cpp
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class S>
S<int, std::dynamic_extent> GetSpan()
{
    return v;
}
```

To make it work with a custom `span`-like type as well as `std::span` you could possibly make it take a non-type parameter pack `std::size_t...` or `auto...`.

```cpp
template <template <typename, std::size_t...> class S>
auto GetSpan()
{
    return S(v);
}
```

Comment: Can I use `template <template <typename...> class S>` to be more generic. I need to instantiate the same function with a in-house span type which doesn't have extent argument.

Comment: @aep no, its a type and a non-type template argument. Unfortunately they dont mix well

Comment: But, `template <template <typename, auto...> class S` seems to work. I assume this can also be instantiated with `MySpanType<T>`.

Comment: @aep oh right, `...` is `0...N` thats why its fine

Answer (score 5):

`std::span` has two template arguments not one. Even though the second has a default, `template <typename> class S` is not correct, as it expects a template with only one type argument. I believe it is a gcc extension to accept the code. Anyhow this compiles also with clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6};

template <template <typename,size_t> class S>  // correct template arguments
auto GetSpan()
{
    return S(v);   // ctad
}

int main()
{
    auto x = GetSpan<std::span>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zzhEeqa7x)